# accessing a boolean in an object using a method vanilla java script

Tags: javascript, methods, factory

I am creating a factory and trying to put some methods onto it. I am testing with simple console.logs. The method that logs a string works (logTitle), the one that references a boolean (logCompleated) (which i later want to change with an updated method that will toggle compleated from true to false and back) does not work. I get "arrayFunctions.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: compleated is not defined" comments in the code to highlight problem. Thanks in advance.

```
const todoFactory = (
  title,
  project = "",
  dueDate = "",
  priority = "",
  notes = ""
) => {
 
  return {
    title,
    project,
    dueDate,
    priority,
    notes,
    compleated: false,
    logTitle: () => console.log(title), //works
    logCompleated: () => console.log(compleated), //arrayFunctions.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: compleated is not defined
  };
};
```

Comment: Use a regular `function` and inside it use `this.compleated`

Comment: logCompleated: function () => console.log(this.compleated)   ???

Comment: No, I said a *regular* function created with the `function` keyword, instead of a `=>` function.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I got it working. Any chance you could give me a google search term or a page I can go to to understand what I was doing wrong before ;-)

Comment: I find it strange that arrow function works on the title method but not on the completed one. I would like to understand why..

Comment: My answer tries to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

That `title` works may be misleading you.  That function, even used as a method of your TODO object, is not making reference to the `title` property of the object you've created.  Instead, it refers to the parameter of the factory function.  You can check this by doing something like `return {title: title + 'foobar', project,...}`.  When you call `myTodo.logTitle()` you will log only the value you supplied as a parameter.

You can fix this by adding `compleated` (note: Usual English spelling is "completed") as a local variable before the `return`.

```js
const todoFactory = (
  title,
  project = "",
  dueDate = "",
  priority = "",
  notes = ""
) => {

  return {
    title,
    project,
    dueDate,
    priority,
    notes,
    compleated: false,
    logTitle: () => console.log(title),
    logCompleated: () => console.log(compleated),
  };
};

const todo = todoFactory('foo')

todo.logCompleated()
```

Or you can make it a function expression (using the `function` keyword rather than an arrow) and use `this.compleated` in the body.  Arrow functions have a different behavior regarding `this`.

```js
const todoFactory = (
  title,
  project = "",
  dueDate = "",
  priority = "",
  notes = ""
) => {
  const compleated = false
  return {
    title,
    project,
    dueDate,
    priority,
    notes,
    compleated,
    logTitle: function() {console.log(this.title)},
    logCompleated: function() {console.log(compleated)},
  };
};

const todo = todoFactory('foo')

todo.logCompleated()
```

Comment: scott is there a good resource you can recommend so I can understand this better?  Or just a google search term I can type in. :-) thanks a lot for you answer!

Comment: @suubcity [See this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: It's simply a matter of [scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) in JS.  The object you return has reference to a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that includes the parameters and local variables in your factory function.  You can also learn that [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not have their own bindings to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular function and inside it use this.compleated